# How do I get my <div> to stretch to the whole width of the screen? I tried width 100%

Tags: css, html, width, fullscreen

I'm tying to make a `<div>` that the width of it will stretch to the whole screen.  Right now I have this in CSS:

```
#spacer3 {

width:100%;
height:300px;

}
```

So I believe that it works.  But on my site the div does not stretch the whole way, it's about 5px off on each side.  Any help?

[Here is a link to the site for a example](http://utulu.net)
the div that I'm having an issue with has a black(ish) background and has a image in it.

Thanks for all help in advance!

Comment: Use [css reset](http://www.cssreset.com/).

Answer (score 6):

You should remove the `body`'s margin (or whatever other element is pushing the content), like this:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  You sir, deserve a cookie.